# After git push origin main, nothing happens

Tags: git, github

I am trying to upload a project which has more than 100 files to github.

These are my steps which GitHub wants me to do on Git Bash terminal.

```
cd <my project file>

git init -b main

git add .

git commit -m "First Commit"

git remote add origin <my remote URL>

git remote -v

git push origin main
```

After I press "enter", nothing happens on terminal screen. I also tried to "git clone" and copied the local files but it didn't work though.

How can I solve this problem ? What am I doing wrong ? I am new in Git.

[image]

Comment: Please, edit your post and add a full screen dump of the commands your issued. As you explained it, we cannot help you unfortunately.

Comment: I've indicated it in the picture now. After I enter "git push origin main" it stucks like this.

Comment: does `git push origin main` return from the call? You did not show that.

Comment: It does nothing and this is the problem.

Comment: It's kind of funny that you can read "nothing happens" in the question, and it's not until you see the output of the terminal that you realize, "Oh, you meant that literally." :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that you're stuck in an authentication request point.  IE, because you're using `git` over `https` it needs your github username and password.  Because you're on a windows mingw64 system, its unclear what would be prompting for that password.  But you should either get a graphical or a textual account login screen, and you're not seeing it.  This is what you need to figure out.  Or better, switch to using a `ssh` based login by generating ssh keys and putting the public key in your github account.

Comment: The Git Bash terminal didn't want authentication but when I tried it on VSC terminal, it wanted. Thank you su much. You made my job easier.