# git push takes forever and The GitHub login window doesn't even pop up

Tags: git

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GOxrv.png)

It stays that way all day.
The GitHub login window doesn't even pop up.
any solution?

Comment: Maybe you can do `git push -v` and more logs to debug?

Comment: You are not alone: https://stackoverflow.com/q/67906636/7976758

Answer (score -1):

Try this one

```
git init        //in case you are going to add directory in git first time
git status
git add .
git commit -m"message of commit"
git push origin main
```

Here 'origin' is your remote and 'main' is branch name.
Make sure you will be in main branch.

You can check branches with

```
git branch
```

and `git checkout <branch name>` helps you to navigate through branches.