# Why does Sourcetree take a long time to commit and push changes to origin?

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

As you can see in the screenshot, I am trying to commit some changes.
The problem is that it gets stuck on this screen for hours.

[image: SourceTree screenshot]

This is just one of the many issues I face using Sourcetree. If there's an alternative, please do recommend it.

I tried changing to a different network connection (WiFi and LAN-cable).

I tried committing through Terminal and it shows the following lines

```
$ git status
```

> On branch feature/refresh-token Your branch is ahead of
> 'origin/feature/refresh-token' by 3 commits. (use "git push" to
> publish your local commits)
>
> nothing to commit, working tree clean

```
$ git push
```

> No result/action - Nothing happens

I tried changing the repository path and it shows a different result in the Output window:

[image]

Comment: Do you get the same behavior when committing from the command line? Have you checked that it isn't your internet connection? How about committing to a different repository?

Comment: 1) Tried while connected via WiFi and cabled -> No result.
2) Used the Terminal to commit/push and it said: "Pushing to https://bitbucket.org/repoUrl.git", and nothing happens
3) I didn't commit to a different repo yet

Comment: "*`git push` — Nothing happens*" What exactly is *nothing* here? Git does nothing and returns to the command prompt without an error? Or Git does nothing and **does not return to the command prompt**?

Comment: Nothing happens like: Git returns to the command prompt without an error or any informative message.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [After git push origin main, nothing happens](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67906636/after-git-push-origin-main-nothing-happens) windows mingw64 bug...

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear. What I meant by "*How about committing to a different repository*" was to clone a different repo, and try committing and pushing to that. Not change the remote path. It is to check if this "taking hours to commit" isn't a repo-specific thing.

Comment: Also, when retrying to commit and push *outside of SourceTree*, you need to make new changes to your code, and commit and push those changes. It is to check if this "taking hours to commit" isn't SourceTree-specific.

Comment: @Tassisto: when git returned to the command line, was the exit code zero or non zero (exit status, `$?`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I "solved" this problem by not committing **bitbucket-pipelines.yml** file.

Comment: now try with an empty bitbucket-pipelines.yml file ... :) maybe main branch if it has it it's faster, too?

Comment: well that you can try out fast now ... :)

Answer (score 0):

May be it could be because of minimum limit of bites
try to

```
git config http.postBuffer 524288000
```